# Generating normal distribution weighing constants in a range

Tags: c++, normal-distribution

I have some results whose relevance decreases with distance. I want to weight the result  array elements with constants whose distribution is close to normal or folded normal. At start I want to generate an array with N constants starting from 1 to 0.01 by a function.

The result should be something like the following, ending with a number close to 0.01.

```
const double normalDistWeight[] = { 
    1.000, 0.997, 0.994, 0.989, 0.984, 0.977, 0.970, 0.961, 0.951, 0.939,
    0.926, 0.910, 0.893, 0.874, 0.853, 0.830, 0.805, 0.778, 0.750, 0.719,
    0.687, 0.654, 0.619, 0.584, 0.548, 0.512, 0.476, 0.440, 0.405, 0.370,
    0.337, 0.305, 0.274, 0.246, 0.219, 0.194, 0.171, 0.150, 0.131, 0.114,
    0.098, 0.085, 0.073, 0.063, 0.054, 0.047, 0.040, 0.035, 0.030, 0.027
};
```

Unfortunately I can't use any third party libraries or C++11 features, only plain C++.

**Edit:** Oh, I was over-thinking it... It's just a simple Gaussian error, so exp(-x^2) should work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your to-do list with us. If you're looking to hire a programmer, you are unfortunately on the wrong site.

Comment: Also, by the look of it, you don't want a "distribution" at all. It looks like you're just asking how to compute an exponential. The C library function `exp` should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! Yeah, I was over-thinking it... Lack of sleep... Now it works fine.

Comment: @CreMinES You should delete your question if it is not relevant for answering....

Comment: I think there is enough room on the stackoverflow servers to store an extra question when it may help somebody who is also overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that all you want is an array of values of the [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) corresponding to uniformly spaced points on the positive half-axis, up to a point where the value is about 0.01.

This is straight-forward. The Gaussian function is *f*(*x*) = exp(−*x*<sup>2</sup>), like this:

[image: Gaussian function, from MathWorld]

In the chosen expression, we already have *f*(0) = 1, so all that remains is to find the final point *x* where we have *f*(*x*) = 0.01. Invert: *x* = √−log(0.01) ≈ 2.15.

So all you need to do is evaluate *f* on uniformly spaced points on the interval [0, 2.15].

Comment: Thank you! I was over-thinking the problem.

Comment: You can generate the table here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html

Comment: @scy7he: Are you sure that's what the OP means, wants or needs? Mind you, we're not talking about integrals here.

Comment: Yeah, Kerrek SB is right, I need to do it on program initialization and the size of the table is determined by a parameter.